# seconds counter in VS C# ASP>NET

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to design a simple counter which will just display the seconds in a Label control. That is, just repeat DateTime.Now.Seconds from 0 to 59 and then repeat until the applications is closed.

I have read through some of the other solutions here, and was able to get it working using AJAX, but my question is why does my following code not work?

The code will display the current Second in the Label, but only that one time. It does not repeat for each "Tick". I have tried while(true) loops in various places, but the code never completes (just goes to infinite loop).

I know that there are solutions using JavaScript (and others), but I would like to see this code work, if possible, without any outside scripts. 
Thanks.

```
using System.Timers;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // set the Timer to pass event "Elapsed" every 1 second
                aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            // wire the Event to the EventHandler
                aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            // set the Timer to repeat automatically
                aTimer.Enabled = true;

            // display the output of the doCount method in the text box    
            timeLabel.Text = doCount().ToString();

        }

        // when the Event fires, call the doCount method
        private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {            
                doCount();
        }

        // Each time the doCount method is called, read the current time and output the "Second"
        // back to the timeLabel.Text call.
        public static int doCount()
        {
            int beat = DateTime.Now.Second;
            return beat;
        }  

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were able to get it working with AJAX because AJAX is able to communicate with the server after the initial response has been sent to the client. A regular Web Forms cycle looks like this:

1. Browser sends request to the server
2. Server receives request
3. Server processes request and generates response
4. Server sends response to the client.

After step #4, no more content can be sent from the server to the client unless the client specifically makes a new request (which is basically the definition of AJAX).

There are a couple of ways around this. One is AJAX. The others are forever frames, server sent events, and web sockets (probably a few other obscure ones out there too). With those, you can think of it as the client initiating a connection with the server that is then left open, so that the server can continuously send data to the client.

One consequence of this is that it forces you to think about what you really need the server to do. The client end can accomplish an awful lot, definitely can handle a simple timer and updating the text in a label without involving the server. And when you're writing web applications, you should do as much on the client as possible. You only have one web server with a finite amount of resources, but you can scale much better if you fully take advantage of the resources of each client connected to your site. The server generates the initial HTML for the client, and is needed for database access and accessing various other API's. But if you can do things on the client without using the server (UI manipulation), then go for it!

Comment: Thank you for responding. What you suggested (that the client "can handle a simple timer and updating the text in a label without involving the server" ) is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: (cont'd) .. I just don't know why my code does not do that, which is why I asked.

Comment: If I may ask, is AJAX still a viable solution? Is it still in use, or has it been replaced by something else? I didn't want to use JavaScript because of its bad reputation. Thanks

Comment: @JohnSullivan AJAX is perfectly usable, as is JavaScript. If you dislike some of the language features of JS, then feel free to look into CoffeeScript or [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) (best for C# programmers). If you want to use AJAX with an ASP.NET site, the server side component to use is [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Comment: Mason - thank you very much for taking the time to respond to my question and comments. My dislike of JavaScript is not code-related, rather it is due to the mis-use of it by various malware writers (and as such, outside of this discussion, I suppose). Now that you've assured me that AJAX is a valid way to go, I will do so.

Answer (score 0):

That will never work, because as soon as the request gets processed, server creates a new instance of your page, process it and send immediately to the client. You can't manipulate the output once it was send, which is why you HAVE to use javascript for tasks like this.

You should definitely learn more about web development, because it's really different compared to developing desktop applications. For this reason it may be a better idea to learn MVC and not Webforms, so you have a more clear understanding of what's going on. In Webforms this may confuse people like yourself, because it looks almost the same as if you were developing an application for Windows, but it's just an illusion.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your comments, but regarding "That will never work.." it does work .. once! It just won't repeat itself.  From what you said, it looks like I would need to generate a new instance of the page each time the Timer fires. Granted that would put too much load on the server to be practical, but I still want to see it work... As to your suggestion that I learn more about web development, that is exactly what I am trying to do, and why I occasionally need to ask a question.  .. I see there is a MVC section in my training curriculum a little later on, which I will get to in time.

Comment: @JohnSullivan, it can't repeat itself, because the response was already sent to the client. You want to rape HTTP, which is a state-less protocol.

Comment: @JohnSullivan It works once because before the response is sent there was enough time to have the timer elapse *once*. But after that response is sent, you can't update it again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a misunderstanding of how an ASP.NET web page works. You should probably read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Effectively the server renders the page and serves it to the client (browser). After that it only responds to events initiated from the client.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will read it through. As far as "events initiated from the client", I thought that was what I was doing with the Timer.Elapsed event. It works once, it just doesn't repeat.

Comment: @JohnSullivan it works once when the page is being rendered on the server. The resulting HTML and Javascript is then sent to the browser. Nothing more will happen in the browser until a request of some kind id sent to the server.